# best way to join map keys/values comma separated

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a map that looks like (it's not constant and there could be more subarrays)

```
var mMp=    new Map([
    [ "A", [1, "r"] ],
    [ "B", [2, "d "]]
    ]);
```

I am trying to get to:

```
var ks = "A, B"
var vs1 = "1, 2"
var vs2 = "r, d"
```

I could do

```
mMp.forEach( (val, key) => {.....};
```

where I add the stuff manually, but I'd have to check for the last value. I also thought about

```
Array.from(mMp.keys()).join(", ");
```

but that also would not help with the values, i guess. And it's less efficient, although I'm not too worried about efficiency here.

What's the best way I can get those 3 sets for strings?
Thank you!

Comment: could be there more than 2 subarrays? `[ "A", [1, "r"] ],
    [ "B", [2, "d "]], ["C", [3, "e "]]` ?

Comment: yes, the number of subarrays is not constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.from` is indeed the way to go. For the values, use [`.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) instead of `.keys()` and the callback:

```
var mMp = new Map([
  ["A", [1, "r"]],
  ["B", [2, "d"]],
  // …
]);
var ks = Array.from(mMp.keys()).join(", "); // "A, B"
var vs1 = Array.from(mMp.values(), v => v[0]).join(", "); // "1, 2"
var vs2 = Array.from(mMp.values(), v => v[1]).join(", "); // "r, d"
```

If you have value arrays of arbitrary lengths, use a loop to create all your `vs` arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Spread the Map to get the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries), then [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) them, and collect the results to separate arrays using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the arrays to strings, and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the results to separate variables (3 in this case):

```js
const mMp = new Map([["A", [1, "r"]], ["B", [2, "d"]], ["C", [3, "e"]], [ "D", [2, "E"]], ["F", [3, "e"]]]);

const [ks, vs1, vs2] = [...mMp].reduce((r, [k, s]) => {
  [k, ...s].forEach((c, i) => r[i] ? r[i].push(c) : r.push([c]));
  
  return r;
}, []).map((arr) => arr.join(', '));

console.log(ks);
console.log(vs1);
console.log(vs2);
```

Comment: unfortunately, it won't work if we have more than 3 subarrays, check `new Map([
      ["A", [1, "r"]],
      ["B", [2, "d "]],
      ["C", [3, "e "]],  [ "B", [2, "d "]], ["C", [3, "e "]]
    ])`

Comment: Updated the example with your Map (changed the keys to be unique).

Comment: His code is working perfectly fine (+1). @ori you could also replace the inner `.forEach` with `.map`: `return [k, v, s].map((c, i) => r[i].concat(c));`.

Comment: @cyrix - thanks. Nice idea :) I know I can save a line, but that will require creating a lot of disposable arrays, so I'll leave it with forEach.

Comment: The function you're expressing here is commonly known as `zip`, and can be expressed more generally as `input.reduce((p, c) => c.map((v, i) => [...(p[i] || []), v]), [])`. E.g. applying the above to `[[1, "r"], [2, "d"]]` results in `[[1, 2], ["r", "d"]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for arbitrary numbers of key value pairs and arbitrary lengths of value arrays:

```
var mMp = new Map([
  ["A", [1, "r"]],
  ["B", [2, "d "]]
]);

const keys = Array.from(mMp.keys())
const vals = Array.from(mMp.values())
    .reduce((p, c) => c.map((v, i) => [...(p[i] || []), v]), [])

const [ks, ...vs] = [keys, ...vals].map(a => a.join(", "))
console.log(ks, vs[0], vs[1]);

// "A, B", "1, 2", "r, d "
```

The `.reduce` bit is a somewhat naive implementation of the `zip` function available in various libraries. If you can use [_.zip](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zip) from lodash, it's a good idea to just use that.

Comment: Why `concat`? Just write `[keys, ..._.zip(vals)]`.

Comment: @Bergi I am applying the mapping over `Array#join` uniformly to both key pairs and value pairs. This is why the extra embedding in an array for the keys.

Comment: I understand what your code is doing, but since you're using ES6 I'm just pointing out that this is the perfect use case for the array spread syntax.

Comment: this is giving me this error: c.map is not a function